# How do I work with ES6 modules in Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have the following class inside `/lib/Test.js`:

```
export class Test {
    constructor() {
        console.log("this is a test");
    }
}
```

and in my `main.js` I'm trying to do the following:

```
import { Test } from "Test";
console.log(Test);
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new (require('/alloy/controllers/' + name))(args)')
```

How can I work with ES6 modules in Titanium?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SDK 8.3.0.GA and the following syntax works just fine:

app/lib/services/myclass.js

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(prop1) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }

  get something() {
    return this.calcSomething();
  }

  calcSomething() {
    return this.prop1 * 2;
  }
}

module.exports = MyClass;
```

and then in app/controllers/index.js

```
import MyClass from 'services/myclass';

let myClass = new MyClass(2);
alert(myClass.something);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. This post is pretty old so I have not tested it on newer SDKs - will give it another shot.

Comment: Yes, I've realised that it's an old post, but just wanted to let you/anyone else who is interested know that it's possible.